# pigeonhole question with sets and sum of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

This question is meant to be solved with pigeonhole principle. But I can't solve it. I just can't figure out what is the pigeon and what is the pigeon hole. I don't really have a clear direction.

**Definition**: if $X$ is a set of non-negative integers, $\sum X$ is defined to be the summary of all the elements of $X$, for example: if $X =\{2,7,13,20\}$ then $\sum X = 2+7+13+20=42$

**Question**: let $C \subset \{0,1,2,...,102\}$, $|C| = 10$ ($C$ has 10 elements).

Show that there are sets $A,B \subset C$, such that $A \neq B \neq \emptyset$ and $\sum A = \sum B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  how many subsets of $C$ are there?  What is the maximum for $\sum C$?

Comment: $C$ has $2^{10} = 1024$ subsets, and $max(\sum C) = 975$

Comment: OK, your subsets are pigeons

Comment: Yeah I got that :) thanks, it's very clear now. top answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why is it $2^{10}$ subsets ?

Comment: @GinKin:  Each element of $C$ can be in the subset or not.  Two choices for one element, $2^{10}$ for $10$ of them.

Comment: How can this number be not related to the total elements in the set i.e. 102 ?

Comment: @GinKin:  Any $10$ element set has $2^{10}$ subsets.  The number $102$ doesn't come in to it.  We needed $102$ to make sure $\sum C$ was small enough that there weren't too many pigeonholes.